# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined on Onclick

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a problem in my function, can anyone help

```
function OnClick1(s, e) {
    var actionParams = $("form").attr("action").split("?OutputFormat=");
    actionParams[1] = s.GetMainElement().getAttribute("OutputFormatAttribute");
    $("form").attr("action", actionParams.join("?OutputFormat="));
}
```

Error is coming from `.split("?OutputFormat=");` saying that

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

can anyone help me in this solution.

Comment: what would be the value when you execute this code? `$("form").attr("action")` Are you sure that, you have an attribute called action in any of your forms?

Comment: It would be helpful to show your HTML as well.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy question itself says split of undefined . he tried to split something which is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Reason is there is no value in `$("form").attr("action")` . you can override it by using conditional statement like this,

```
actionParams = $("form").attr("action") ? $("form").attr("action").split("?OutputFormat=") : null
```

so, here if you have value it will do split function otherwise it will return `null`